# Bulk Copy C# to PostgreSql

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I have a data table with 1000 of records. I want to perform a bulk insert operation from C# to PGSQL. I know one way which copies a text file to `pgtable`.

The example syntax is as follows:

```
using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;Database=postgres;"))
{
    onn.Open();
    NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("copy \"schema\".\"tablename\" (\"col1\",\"col2\") from 'C:\\datafile.txt'", conn);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Is there any other function which I can use to pass the data table instead of writing data into a text file? I m using `Npgsql.dll`.

Answer (score 6):

You should probably fully read the [PostgreSQL docs for COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html).

COPY can either be used to import a file that exists in the PostgreSQL server filesystem (as your code sample shows), or it can be used to copy data from the client, which is probably what you're looking for. The latter is triggered by substituting `STDIN` for the filename.

If you want to import data from your client program using Npgsql, please read the [Npgsql COPY docs](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html) as well. For textual data import you'll likely need to call `NpgsqlConnection.BeginTextImport()`, there's a sample for that in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

```
public bool CopyFileToPostgress(String tableName, String filePath,String delimiter)
    {
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Host=xx.xx.xx.xx;port=xxxx;Database=xxxx;Username=xxxx;Password=xxxx;Pooling=false;Timeout=300;CommandTimeout=300");
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
        Boolean result = true;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                try
                {
                    NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand($"COPY {tableName} FROM '{filePath}' (DELIMITER '{delimiter}')", conn);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    result = false;
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    throw e;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (result)
                    {
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                    transaction.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
        return result;
    }
```