# Bulk insert / copy iEnumerable into table with npgsql

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, npgsql

I have a method that takes in an IEnumerable, and loops through the IEnumerable and inserts each into a table in the DB. like so:

```
    public void Write(IEnumerable<foo> fooData)
    {
            for (var index = 0; index < fooData.Count(); index++)
            {
               var sql = @"insert into foo (col_id, col_name) values (@col_id, col_name)";
            }
    }
```

foo is a class that reflects the table in the db:

```
      public class Foo
      {
        public int col_id {get;set;}
        public string col_name {get;set;}
      }
```

its come to light that using a for loop is not efficient if my row has thousands of entries. What is  more efficient way of copying all this data when an IEnumerable is concerned?

Comment: If you need speed, check COPY: https://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html

Comment: how would this transfer from an ienumerable? would i need a for loop?

Comment: Yep, you would do the same for loop over your data, but rather than executing SQL INSERT statements, you'd use the COPY binary import API instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bulk Copy C# to PostgreSql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42414338/bulk-copy-c-sharp-to-postgresql)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have written a class that behaves like the inbuilt SqlBulkCopy class for Postgres.  It wraps the `COPY` command to provide fast uploads. The method for IEnumerable looks like this (there is a similar one for `DataTable`).

```
public void WriteToServer<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
{
    try
    {
        if (DestinationTableName == null || DestinationTableName == "")
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("DestinationTableName", "Destination table must be set");
        }
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        int colCount = properties.Length;

        NpgsqlDbType[] types = new NpgsqlDbType[colCount];
        int[] lengths = new int[colCount];
        string[] fieldNames = new string[colCount];

        using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + DestinationTableName + " LIMIT 1", conn))
        {
            using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (rdr.FieldCount != colCount)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("dataTable", "Column count in Destination Table does not match column count in source table.");
                }
                var columns = rdr.GetColumnSchema();
                for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
                {
                    types[i] = (NpgsqlDbType)columns[i].NpgsqlDbType;
                    lengths[i] = columns[i].ColumnSize == null ? 0 : (int)columns[i].ColumnSize;
                    fieldNames[i] = columns[i].ColumnName;
                }
            }

        }
        var sB = new StringBuilder(fieldNames[0]);
        for (int p = 1; p < colCount; p++)
        {
            sB.Append(", " + fieldNames[p]);
        }
        using (var writer = conn.BeginBinaryImport("COPY " + DestinationTableName + " (" + sB.ToString() + ") FROM STDIN (FORMAT BINARY)"))
        {
            foreach (var t in data)
            {
                writer.StartRow();

                for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
                {
                    if (properties[i].GetValue(t) == null)
                    {
                        writer.WriteNull();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        switch (types[i])
                        {
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Bigint:
                                writer.Write((long)properties[i].GetValue(t), types[i]);
                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Bit:
                                if (lengths[i] > 1)
                                {
                                    writer.Write((byte[])properties[i].GetValue(t), types[i]);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    writer.Write((byte)properties[i].GetValue(t), types[i]);
                                }
                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Boolean:
                                writer.Write((bool)properties[i].GetValue(t), types[i]);
                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Bytea:
                                writer.Write((byte[])properties[i].GetValue(t), types[i]);
                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Char:
                                if (properties[i].GetType() == typeof(string))
                                {
                                    writer.Write((string)properties[i].GetValue(t), types[i]);
                                }
                                else if (properties[i].GetType() == typeof(Guid))
                                {
                                    var value = properties[i].GetValue(t).ToString();
                                    writer.Write(value, types[i]);
                                }


                                else if (lengths[i] > 1)
                                {
                                    writer.Write((char[])properties[i].GetValue(t), types[i]);
                                }
                                else
                                {

                                    var s = ((string)properties[i].GetValue(t).ToString()).ToCharArray();
                                    writer.Write(s[0], types[i]);
                                }
                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Time:
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp:
                            case NpgsqlDbType.TimestampTz:
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Date:
                                writer.Write((DateTime)properties[i].GetValue(t), types[i]);
                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Double:
                                writer.Write((double)properties[i].GetValue(t), types[i]);
                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Integer:
                                try
                                {
                                    if (properties[i].GetType() == typeof(int))
                                    {
                                        writer.Write((int)properties[i].GetValue(t), types[i]);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    else if (properties[i].GetType() == typeof(string))
                                    {
                                        var swap = Convert.ToInt32(properties[i].GetValue(t));
                                        writer.Write((int)swap, types[i]);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    string sh = ex.Message;
                                }

                                writer.Write((object)properties[i].GetValue(t), types[i]);
                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Interval:
                                writer.Write((TimeSpan)properties[i].GetValue(t), types[i]);
                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Numeric:
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Money:
                                writer.Write((decimal)properties[i].GetValue(t), types[i]);
                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Real:
                                writer.Write((Single)properties[i].GetValue(t), types[i]);
                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Smallint:

                                try
                                {
                                    if (properties[i].GetType() == typeof(byte))
                                    {
                                        var swap = Convert.ToInt16(properties[i].GetValue(t));
                                        writer.Write((short)swap, types[i]);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    writer.Write((short)properties[i].GetValue(t), types[i]);
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    string ms = ex.Message;
                                }

                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Varchar:
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Text:
                                writer.Write((string)properties[i].GetValue(t), types[i]);
                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Uuid:
                                writer.Write((Guid)properties[i].GetValue(t), types[i]);
                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Xml:
                                writer.Write((string)properties[i].GetValue(t), types[i]);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            writer.Complete();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error executing NpgSqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer().  See inner exception for details", ex);
    }
}
```

You need to set the Property DestinationTableName first and conn needs to be an open connection.

Essentially the method uses `Reflection` to get the properties of the type of the passed list. Obviously the data types of the table being filled have to match!  The writer builds up by iterating through the list, and then does one bulk insert at the end.  I may not have dealt with all the types that you need, but it should be clear how to add them, where they are missing.

EDIT

Having been asked to share it, here is the equivalent for DataTable:

```
public void WriteToServer(DataTable dataTable)
{
    try
    {
        if (DestinationTableName == null || DestinationTableName == "")
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("DestinationTableName", "Destination table must be set");
        }
        int colCount = dataTable.Columns.Count;

        NpgsqlDbType[] types = new NpgsqlDbType[colCount];
        int[] lengths = new int[colCount];
        string[] fieldNames = new string[colCount];

        using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + DestinationTableName + " LIMIT 1", conn))
        {
            using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (rdr.FieldCount != colCount)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("dataTable", "Column count in Destination Table does not match column count in source table.");
                }
                var columns = rdr.GetColumnSchema();
                for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
                {
                    types[i] = (NpgsqlDbType)columns[i].NpgsqlDbType;
                    lengths[i] = columns[i].ColumnSize == null ? 0 : (int)columns[i].ColumnSize;
                    fieldNames[i] = columns[i].ColumnName;
                }
            }

        }
        var sB = new StringBuilder(fieldNames[0]);
        for (int p = 1; p < colCount; p++)
        {
            sB.Append(", " + fieldNames[p]);
        }
        using (var writer = conn.BeginBinaryImport("COPY " + DestinationTableName + " (" + sB.ToString() + ") FROM STDIN (FORMAT BINARY)"))
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataTable.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                DataRow dR = dataTable.Rows[j];
                writer.StartRow();

                for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
                {
                    if (dR[i] == DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        writer.WriteNull();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        switch (types[i])
                        {
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Bigint:
                                writer.Write((long)dR[i], types[i]);
                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Bit:
                                if (lengths[i] > 1)
                                {
                                    writer.Write((byte[])dR[i], types[i]);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    writer.Write((byte)dR[i], types[i]);
                                }
                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Boolean:
                                writer.Write((bool)dR[i], types[i]);
                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Bytea:
                                writer.Write((byte[])dR[i], types[i]);
                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Char:
                                if (dR[i] is string)
                                {
                                    writer.Write((string)dR[i], types[i]);
                                }
                                else if (dR[i] is Guid)
                                {
                                    var value = dR[i].ToString();
                                    writer.Write(value, types[i]);
                                }


                                else if (lengths[i] > 1)
                                {
                                    writer.Write((char[])dR[i], types[i]);
                                }
                                else
                                {

                                    var s = ((string)dR[i].ToString()).ToCharArray();
                                    writer.Write(s[0], types[i]);
                                }
                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Time:
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp:
                            case NpgsqlDbType.TimestampTz:
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Date:
                                writer.Write((DateTime)dR[i], types[i]);
                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Double:
                                writer.Write((double)dR[i], types[i]);
                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Integer:
                                try
                                {
                                    if (dR[i] is int)
                                    {
                                        writer.Write((int)dR[i], types[i]);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    else if (dR[i] is string)
                                    {
                                        var swap = Convert.ToInt32(dR[i]);
                                        writer.Write((int)swap, types[i]);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    string sh = ex.Message;
                                }

                                writer.Write((object)dR[i], types[i]);
                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Interval:
                                writer.Write((TimeSpan)dR[i], types[i]);
                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Numeric:
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Money:
                                writer.Write((decimal)dR[i], types[i]);
                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Real:
                                writer.Write((Single)dR[i], types[i]);
                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Smallint:

                                try
                                {
                                    if (dR[i] is byte)
                                    {
                                        var swap = Convert.ToInt16(dR[i]);
                                        writer.Write((short)swap, types[i]);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    writer.Write((short)dR[i], types[i]);
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    string ms = ex.Message;
                                }

                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Varchar:
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Text:
                                writer.Write((string)dR[i], types[i]);
                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Uuid:
                                writer.Write((Guid)dR[i], types[i]);
                                break;
                            case NpgsqlDbType.Xml:
                                writer.Write((string)dR[i], types[i]);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            writer.Complete();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error executing NpgSqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer().  See inner exception for details", ex);
    }
}
```

As with the `IEnumerable` implementation, there may be some data types missing, but it is easy to extend.

Comment: Hey, I just came across this. Can you share the same for Datatable?

Answer (score 1):

I use this https://github.com/PostgreSQLCopyHelper/PostgreSQLCopyHelper its very fast.

Here is an example, I am loading a list of instances of my custom class (called single_bar which has 6 variables, as opposed to your Foo class with your 2). The Copy helper maps the variables in your class to the columns you wish to write to.

```
            //  We make a copy helper, to upload to the DB
            PostgreSQLCopyHelper<single_bar> copyHelper = new PostgreSQLCopyHelper<single_bar>(temp_table_name)
                                                            .MapTimeStamp("bar_time", x => x.bar_time)
                                                            .MapReal("open_px", x => x.open_px)
                                                            .MapReal("high_px", x => x.high_px)
                                                            .MapReal("low_px", x => x.low_px)
                                                            .MapReal("close_px", x => x.close_px)
                                                            .MapReal("trade_volume", x => x.getrealvol());

            //  Upload the data to the temp table.
            ulong NoUploaded = copyHelper.SaveAll(conn, dataset);
            result = Convert.ToInt32(NoUploaded);
```

I created a temporary table as the target for the copy action then do an upsert across to the final table.