# Is there any suitable replacement for SqlBulkCopy in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

I am trying to convert the code for a database and the only thing I need to convert that is left is the SqlBulkCopy to PostgreSQL. Any recommendations?

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65687071/bulk-insert-copy-ienumerable-into-table-with-npgsql/65701069#65701069)

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551 You should also tell us which programming language that is.

Comment: Assuming you are using .NET (To a_horse_with_no_name's point, you should specify in your question), can you also include what you'd expect your source data types to be?  Are you wanting to bulk load data from a CSV, directly from another table, or from a table within the existing database?